# Powering a 7 inch touchscreen for the Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen

I ordered a 7 inch hdmi touchscreen for the Raspberry Pi 3 on ebay and started developing my Python openCV application.

So my setup is a Raspberry Pi 3 + webcam + 7 inch touchscreen powered via usb

During development I noticed a lightning bolt icon in the upper right corner.
It is a undervoltage warning, so I ordered a 3A power adapter.
But this didn't help.

I also noticed my webcam video framerate performance was horrible, but as soon is I powered the touchscreen with a 2nd power adapter instead of via the Pi all my speed and power problems disappeared. The downside is that I don't have any touch input now.

The original setup with touchscreen powered via the Pi draws around 1.1Amps
The touchscreen itself draws around 0.9amps

This is measured with a usb power meter, but I'm hesitated if the results are correct, because this will mean Raspberry + webcam is only 0.2amps with running opencv application with 55% CPU.

Are the 4 USB on the raspberry limited to a certain amount of milliamps?

Update: In my /boot/config.txt my max_usb_current is already default set on 1

Comment: Maybe someone else will explain better, but I think you can connect both an adapter and the Pi to the screen? So, I mean, have two adapters, plus the USB connection.

Comment: Well the touchscreen X and Y position is send over the same usb, that is why I'm missing touch input as soon as I use two adapters

Comment: I thought you disconnected the Pi from the screen to connect the adapter?

Comment: Exactly, so then your touchscreen gets power via an external power adapter, but your touch input X and Y coordinates has to send to the raspberry.

Comment: So what I was suggesting is to keep the connection Pi-screen and then also add a 2nd adapter. If the screen has only one port you need a Y-adapter or something. I think this should work.

Comment: I just ordered a micro USB to two usb type A Y cable. If I get lucky I can use two usb ports from the PI to power the touchscreen. I think they have a limit per port?

Comment: Yes, and then the Pi will have a total limit also. You should try to use two adapters I think.

Comment: @TomasBy I saw you had a similar topic in your profile. Did you get it solved? I'll keep you updated

Comment: No I don't think I got any further, but I am not using that adapter any more.

Comment: The USB ports on the Pi are unregulated in the sense that you will not get more power by drawing from two of them instead of one.  What you could try is a powered USB hub, this would allow you to power the screen independently and get the data connection from it.